# Is there a way to deploy Ruby on Rails on a Windows Server?

Tags: ruby, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4, web-deployment, windows-server-2012

We've been trying many different ways to deploy Ruby on Rails on a Windows Server but to no avail. Can someone teach us or at least send me a link of instruction how to deploy on a windows server.

By the way we use MS SQL and Rails 4

Thanks!

Comment: the guides are mostly 2000's and it only runs on ruby 1.8.3 and another thing is that we use MS SQL.

Answer (score 0):

RailsInstaller is the quickest way to go from zero to developing Ruby on Rails applications. Whether you're on Windows or Mac, RailsInstaller has you covered.

http://railsinstaller.org/

PS. Be advised it is Ruby 1.9

Comment: Have you checked Daniel Kehoe's site? http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html